# squid-deb-proxy failing to cache packages

Tags: server, apt, package-management, proxy, squid-deb-proxy

On an Ubuntu 12.04 server, with `squid-deb-proxy` installed, client machines on the network will properly contact the server when installing packages, but `squid` never caches packages.

From `/var/log/squid-deb-proxy/access.log`:

```
1368371692.721    485 192.168.1.220 TCP_MISS/200 20304 GET http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cowsay/cowsay_3.03+dfsg1-3_all.deb - DIRECT/91.189.91.13 application/x-debian-package
1368371721.534    264 192.168.1.210 TCP_MISS/200 20304 GET http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cowsay/cowsay_3.03+dfsg1-3_all.deb - DIRECT/91.189.91.13 application/x-debian-package
```

Both 192.168.1.220 & .210 contacted the server (.210 *is* the server, but also has `squid-deb-proxy-client` installed), but .210 received `TCP_MISS/200`, instead of being served the cached package.

From `/var/log/squid-deb-proxy/store.log`:

```
1368371692.721 RELEASE -1 FFFFFFFF 1255C76AE7E24BA02B4ABB6A3E4AB535  200 1368371672 1293023126        -1 application/x-debian-package 19904/19904 GET http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cowsay/cowsay_3.03+dfsg1-3_all.deb
1368371721.534 RELEASE -1 FFFFFFFF 3534FA3574ED95020E8C960C75129676  200 1368371700 1293023126        -1 application/x-debian-package 19904/19904 GET http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cowsay/cowsay_3.03+dfsg1-3_all.deb
```

If I'm reading the `store.log` right, `squid` cached two copies of the exact same file.  (I used `cowsay` to test; much larger files, like `linux-headers-*` also were never cached.)

The only changes from the default `squid-deb-proxy.conf` were to enable mirrors:

```
81,82c81,82
< http_access deny !to_ubuntu_mirrors
< #http_access allow !to_ubuntu_mirrors
---
> #http_access deny !to_ubuntu_mirrors
> http_access allow !to_ubuntu_mirrors
86,87c86,87
< cache deny !to_ubuntu_mirrors
< #cache allow !to_ubuntu_mirrors
---
> #cache deny !to_ubuntu_mirrors
> cache allow !to_ubuntu_mirrors
```

Lastly, the only errors I have seen in `squid`-specific logs are:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/upstart/squid-deb-proxy.log.1
2013/05/09 09:27:05| Warning: empty ACL: acl blockedpkgs urlpath_regex "/etc/squid-deb-proxy/autogenerated/pkg-blacklist-regexp.acl"
2013/05/09 09:27:05| WARNING: (B) '::/0' is a subnetwork of (A) '::/0'
2013/05/09 09:27:05| WARNING: because of this '::/0' is ignored to keep splay tree searching predictable
2013/05/09 09:27:05| WARNING: You should probably remove '::/0' from the ACL named 'all'
```

Given that the clients are correctly contacting the server's proxy, why won't `squid` cache & return the packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After starting from scratch (purging & re-installing), I finally discovered the problem.

The changes to `squid-deb-proxy.conf` (which I *thought* enabled mirrors) were the culprits.

I don't understand the comments in the file, like: "`# uncomment the third and fouth line to permit any unlisted domain`".  There are only **two** lines underneath that comment, and uncommenting both lines would seem (to someone unversed in `squid`'s configuration syntax) to negate each other.  Reversing the options (commenting out the originally uncommented one, and activating the originally commented one) obviously did not work.

One other point: the autogenerated files are sensitive to backup files in the `*.d/` directories.  I noticed that `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/autogenerated/mirror-dstdomain.acl` had the contents of both `mirror-dstdomain.acl.d/10-default` and `mirror-dstdomain.acl.d/10-default~` in it.